# Filling joint between backer board and wall in shower

Tags: shower, patching-drywall

I've never done home repairs before)

I just moved into a place and noticed GLOBS of silicone caulk in the walls next to the shower, it looked hideous.  I went to shave some down and maybe recaulk a nicer bead, turned out the previous person used it to seal with tile backer with the wall.

[image: Exposed joint]

Is this the proper way to do it?

My solution currently would be to patch it with joint compound to make it flush with the wall, and maybe caulk over the border with the tile.  Is there a more proper way to do this? I'm concerned over keeping it waterproof.  It appears the shower did have water leakage issues in the past.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a close-up of that corner, showing the materials? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: The proper way is to pick either that curtain rod or buy new doors. A new door would hide most of that, not that waterproofing all the way up there maters. Patch it with w/e. But if you take the old track off take a good look at the bottom end; that's where it'd leak.

Comment: Since no update from op I would suggest trim boards but , at this point no response to an answer or comments time to close.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use joint compound that close to the shower. That gap at the top probably goes all the way to the bottom behind the door track and should be fixed too. Remove the door track and scrap all the caulk off everything: walls, tile, door track. Get some epoxy grout from your home store and spread it from the bottom of the shower all the way to the top, filling in that space between the wall and the tile. Follow directions for the grout. Once the grout hardens reinstall the shower door track and get a good paintable caulk and run beads on both sides of the door track and at the bottom. good luck

Comment: Epoxy grout is a good way to go here it handles the different materials well and is solid but somewhat flexible.